# Is there a way to work with time period iterations on Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, email, win32com

I'm using a for loop in Python to send emails depending of a few conditions that are specified.
Every iteration will send an email. Is there a way to every iteration takes something like a few seconds to ocurr?
I would like this way not to sent too many emails in one time.

Comment: Try [sleep](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep)

Comment: `time.sleep(3)`?